# Javaassist source error while instrumenting a method

Tags: java, reflection, instrumentation

I am trying to instrument a method in one of my entities (com.xxx.entity.Order):

```
private String getLookupMethodString() {
    return new StringBuilder(
            "public java.lang.String lookupCustomValue(java.lang.String fieldName) throws java.lang.IllegalAccessException, java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException, java.beans.IntrospectionException {").append(
            "java.lang.String mappingFieldName =  \"value1\";").append(
            "com.xxx.entity.CustomFieldValue cfv = (com.xxx.entity.CustomFieldValue) new java.beans.PropertyDescriptor(\"customFieldValue\", getClass()).getReadMethod().invoke(this);").append(
            "return (java.lang.String) new java.beans.PropertyDescriptor(mappingFieldName, com.xxx.entity.CustomFieldValue.class).getReadMethod().invoke(cfv);}").toString();
}

public byte[] transform(ClassLoader clazzLoader, String className, Class<?> clazz, ProtectionDomain arg3, byte[] rawBytes) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
    CtClass cl = pool.makeClass(new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(rawBytes));
    String lookupMethodString = getLookupMethodString();
    CtMethod lookupMethod = CtMethod.make(lookupMethodString, cl); // Error encountered at this line.
    cl.addMethod(lookupMethod);
}
```

The field customFieldValue has also been instrumented in this class, hence I am using reflection to fetch its value. The error I get on executing this is:

```
[source error] invoke(com.xxx.entity.CustomFieldValue) not found in java.lang.reflect.Method
```

Can somebody please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work, the issue was with the invocation of invoke method. When tried to call invoke method with second argument as null, it worked. (Not pretty sure why?)

```
return (java.lang.String) new java.beans.PropertyDescriptor(mappingFieldName, com.xxx.entity.CustomFieldValue.class).getReadMethod().invoke(cfv, null);}").toString();
```